# Where can I find hplip debug documentation?

Tags: monitoring, hplip

I need to monitor HP printer state (ink, paper, etc). Hplip has hp-info tool with debug-mode and very verbose output. But I can't find any documentation with explanation of its data. For example:

```
hp-info[31896]: debug: printer_status=1
hp-info[31896]: debug: device_status=2
hp-info[31896]: debug: cover_status=4
hp-info[31896]: debug: detected_error_state=64 (0x40)
hp-info[31896]: debug: Printer status=1000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is no complete documentation for hp-info command. All that you
>   can find is in hp-info - -help (or) man hp-info command. HPLIP is a
>   open source project and you can find the complete source code of hplip
>   @ http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/gethplip.html. You can explore
>   through the source code to get more info on the data listed by hp-info
>   command. Most of it is contained in codes.py & models.dat file of the
>   source.

[Source](https://answers.launchpad.net/hplip/+question/239172)